# Ansible Permission denied (public key) but ssh using same key works

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-ad-hoc

I'm running this Ansible ad-hoc command on Ubuntu 16.x (ansible ver. 2.2.1.0 and 2.2.2.0)

```
ansible host_alias -a "df -h" -u USER
```

where host_alias is the defined the ansible hosts file (defines an ec2 instance and its .pem file).

the host file looks like this:

```
[host_alias]

my_host.compute.amazonaws.com

private_key_file=/path/to/key/my_key.pem
```

I get this error:

```
private_key_file=/path/to/key/my_key.pem | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname private_key_file=/path/to/key/my_key.pem: Name or service not known\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
}
my_host.compute.amazonaws.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n", 
    "unreachable": true
```

The same host and key work fine when I ssh (defined by `~/.ssh/config`).
I have made triple sure the key is there and has read permissions.  I also tried setting the `ansible_user` in the Ansible hosts file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the format of the Ansible [inventory file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups) in the documentation.

You have defined two hosts in a host group named `host_alias`:

- the first host is: `my_host.compute.amazonaws.com`,
- the second host is: `private_key_file=/path/to/key/my_key.pem`.

Ansible complains it cannot connect to the second host:

> Could not resolve hostname private_key_file=/path/to/key/my_key.pem

It also cannot connect to the first host, because the SSH key is not defined:

> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey).

---

On top of the mistake of splitting the hostname and the parameter into separate lines, you also got the name of the parameter wrong -- it should be `ansible_ssh_private_key_file`.

The parameters are listed in a later section of [the same document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters).

---

Your inventory file should look like this:

```
[host_group_name]
my_host.compute.amazonaws.com ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/path/to/key/my_key.pem
```

and your command:

```
ansible host_group_name -a "df -h" -u USER
```

Comment: Thank you so much techraf!   After making your changes I had to do two more things.  Pass a -u USER on my my ansible cmd (I know I can add it to the ansible hosts file).  And secondly, after adding the user, I got an error indicating the name was too long.  I seem to remember this is why I must have tried breaking up the lines with a new line.  I fixed the char length issue by using the IP.  I can live with that.  All good now.  Thank you!

Comment: Most likely you are referring to this issue: [ssh throws 'unix domain socket "too long"' error](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/11536). There are some solutions suggested.

Answer (score -1):

The second line needs to be dropped in the 
[host_alias] section.
The above section is meant for hosts only.
Once you do that try

ansible all -m ping

to check if you can ping the host.